# How do I authenticate a cookie and then redirect to the homepage or the inputted URL if the cookie is correct in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, redirect, cookies

The logic is rather primitive - if a user visits the page and does not have the cookie, which shows that the user accepted/denied cookies he gets redirected to a cookie acceptance page. When he's set the cookie, he gets redirected to the previous inputted URL or the homepage (depending which URL the user inputted).

How do I realize this in ASP.NET Core (I'm using .NET 6 if that matters)

My pseudocode looks like this:

```
[Route("/*")]
var result = AuthenticateCookie(document.cookie("banneracceptance", true).authenticate());
if (result === true)
Redirect(/Homepage || inputtedURL);
else
throw new Error ("Wrong credentials");
```

Apparently I'm a beginner with C# so I wrote it in JavaScript style.

P.S. which component do I write this logic in? A controller? Startup.cs?

Comment: Just want to double check... on ALL requests you want to have a check to see if they accepted a specific cookie, and if they haven't all requests will go to a certain page. If they have accepted it, they can go to whatever page they were trying to get to as normal. Is that right?

Comment: @BenMatthews exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would best be solved by using some custom middleware for all requests. You put it in the pipeline and then check for the cookie, then redirect if it is not there or doesn't match the value we want. Perhaps also put a check for the page it is requesting but the pipeline might seems to be smart enough not to put you in a redirect loop.

```
public class CookieCheckMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public CookieCheckMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        if(httpContext.Request.Cookies["MyCookie"] == null && httpContext.Request.Path != "/WhereIShouldGo")
        {
            httpContext.Response.Redirect("/WhereIShouldGo");
        }
        await _next(httpContext); // calling next middleware

    }
}

// Extension method used to add the middleware to the HTTP request pipeline.
public static class CookieCheckMiddlewareExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseCookieCheckMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.UseMiddleware<CookieCheckMiddleware>();
    }
}
```

And then in your startup.cs

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    ...

    app.UseCookieCheckMiddleware();

    ...
}
```

Just note that where you put that middleware call, it also goes in the request pipeline, so make sure important stuff is in front of it in the configure method, and things that would depend on the redirect go after it.

Comment: I'm still a beginner in ASP.NET Core, do I put the code in a Controller and somehow import it or how do I accomplish this?

Comment: The CookieCheckMiddleware is it's own class that you can organize how you like.

But it seems as though you gave a good edit and were hitting a redirect loop. Working as you hoped now?

Comment: Yup, it does work as intended now after the edit :-)